# How to use guava Closer properly

Tags: java, exception, lucene, guava

i'm struggling to figure out how to use the [Closer](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained) utility from the guava library. Please see the code below.

- One thing is, that the [IndexWriter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) throws an `IOException` on both object initialization and `close()`. Therefore, the code in the finally and rethrow blocks is underlined.
- The other question is, why do i have to catch `Throwable` instead of other exception types and do i have to rethrow the errors (i would prefer to log those at the spot)

`

```
int getDocumentsCount() {
    Closer closer = Closer.create();
    try {
        IndexWriter iwriter = closer.register(openIndexWriter());
        return iwriter.numDocs();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error(e, e);
        return -1;
    } finally {
        closer.close();
    }
}


IndexWriter openIndexWriter() throws IOException {
    return new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, false,
        IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
}
```

`

Thanks a lot

(stuck with Java 6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Guava's own explanation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained#closer), you *have* to use `Throwable`, yes.

Here's their example snippet:

```
public void foo() throws IOException {
  Closer closer = Closer.create();
  try {
    InputStream in = closer.register(openInputStream());
    OutputStream out = closer.register(openOutputStream());
    // do stuff with in and out
  } catch (Throwable e) { // must catch Throwable
    throw closer.rethrow(e);
  } finally {
    closer.close();
  }
}
```

Note that they catch `Throwable` and rethrow it directly from the `Closer` instance.

As to why it is `Throwable` and not, let's say `IOException` or `RuntimeException`, it's because the `Closer` **must** know that an error occurred so that it can close the resources properly. All is only a matter of doing things proper. So it can work if you don't do it properly, but it's not guaranteed.

Not that if your method can throw `MyOwnCheckedException`, for instance, you **have to** declare them:

```
} catch (Throwable t) {
  throw closer.rethrow(e, MyOwnCheckedException.class);
} finally {
  closer.close();
}
```

Java 7 example, for comparison:

```
public void foo() throws IOException {
  try (InputStream in = openInputStream();
       OutputStream out = openOutputStream();
    // do stuff with in and out
  }
}
```

If you compare the `Closer` example with the Java 7 example, you can see that I still have to declare the `IOException` in the method signature.

---

For your case, this is what you have to do:

```
int getDocumentsCount() {
  try {
    Closer closer = Closer.create();
    try {
       IndexWriter iwriter = closer.register(openIndexWriter());
      return iwriter.numDocs();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      closer.rethrow(e);
    } finally {
      closer.close();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e, e);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

To avoid try-pyramids, I'd do the following:

```
int getDocumentsCount() {
  try {
    return doGetDocumentsCount();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e, e);
    return -1;
  }
}

int doGetDocumentsCount() throws IOException {
  Closer closer = Closer.create();
  try {
    IndexWriter iwriter = closer.register(openIndexWriter());
    return iwriter.numDocs();
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    closer.rethrow(e);
  } finally {
    closer.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) I've seen their example too. The problem is that i get a compilation error in the finally block, because the closer can throw `IOException`. 

2) Do i have to rethrow the exception? I mean, i don't see how it helps the Closer to register the exception. It's the closer, after all, who rethrows the exception, which is caught in the catch block (so it actually is already aware of it).

Comment: No, you don't have to "rethrow" the exception: you have to **declare** it. I've adapted the answer to show that you need to declare the `IOException` being thrown. Keep in mind that `Closer` only handles closing `Closeable`s. It doesn't say anything about handling the exception outside of the `Closer` scope.

Comment: Thanks. 
1) But i don't want to throw the `IOException` at all, it's somewhat irritating that  the `Closer` is not able to handle it, forcing me to declare it in the method signature.

2) What i also don't understand is why i need to rethrow `MyOwnCheckedException`? Is it just a way to convert whatever exception that was thrown by the resource in my own?

Comment: @d56 I've added what you requested in my answer. If you have to add `MyOwnCheckedException.class` in the `rethrow` method, it's to make sure that it is *not* wrapped in a `RuntimeException`. It's for when you are sure you want to throw that exception. I strongly suggest that you carefully read the entire wiki page I linked in my answer (and not only the `Closer` part).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I think "try-pyramid" is what confused me so much in the first place. As i see it, in my small case, using manual resource closing is actually more concise than going with guava.

Comment: @d56: `Closer` doesn't really exist to make resource closing _concise_ so much as it does to make it _correct_, which is next to impossible to do manually without try-with-resources. (It's possible of course, but more complex than almost anyone imagines.)